# Memory Leak Concept - beginner level

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I am a beginner level programmer and trying to understand the concept of memory leaks - mainly in Java as I currently study Java. Would anyone be able to help me whether these examples are memory leak or not?

```
Student s1, s2;

//case I
s1 = new Student("John",20);
s1 = new Student("Mark",19);
// did I just lose the address to John, 20?


//case II:
s1 = new Student("John",20);
s2 = new Student("Mark",19);

s2 = s1;
// did I just lose the address to Mark,19?
```

Comment: Check out Java's garbage collection.

Comment: It's only a memory leak if you are retaining unwanted objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're not memory leaks. A memory leak appears when an object is allocated and can't be garbaged. As you don't keep any reference to the first allocated student (in first example) or to the second one (in the second example), this instance can be garbaged, there's no leak.

Now, imagine you do

```
s1 = new Student("John",20);
myHashMap.put(s1, 33);
s1 = new Student("Mark",19);
myHashMap.put(s1, 43);
```

then you keep a reference to the first version of s1 and if you go on creating students and don't clean the map, **then** you have a memory leak. Maps kept in memory are a frequent case of memory leak.

Note that it's not so frequent to have a memory leak in a sane java program.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have to tell the runtime to take back memory. So a program might look like this:

```
char *pointer = malloc(1024); // ask for a chunk of memory
doSomethingWith(pointer);     // something using the memory
free(pointer);
pointer = malloc(2048); // ask for another chunk of memory
doSomethingWith(pointer);     // something using the memory
free(pointer);
```

If you fail to call free(), then that block of memory stays in use for the life of the program:

```
char *pointer = malloc(1024); // ask for a chunk of memory
doSomethingWith(pointer);     // something using the memory
pointer = malloc(2048); // ask for another chunk of memory
```

In the above code, assuming `doSomethingWith()` hasn't saved it somewhere, we have lost the pointer to the block of 1024 bytes, because we assigned a new value to `pointer`. Without that value, we can't ever free that memory.

As you can imagine, in real code, unless you keep things very organised, it's easy to lose track of all the pointers. You might do a great job of freeing memory when your code is following its happy path, but when it handles errors (file not found; host unavailable etc.) it might miss the `free()`. That's what causes programs to gradually consume more and more memory that they can't ever release.

```
  char *buffer = malloc(1024);
  ssize_t size = read(filehandle,buffer,1024,0)
  if( size != -1 ) {
       doSomethingWith(buffer);
       free(buffer);
  } else {
       perror("Error: ");
       // oops, we have not free()d buffer
  }
```

And that's called a *memory leak*.

In Java, `new` is broadly equivalent to `malloc`, and there is no `free()`. Instead a part of the JVM called the *Garbage Collector* keeps track of every object, and every reference (or in C parlance, "pointer") to it. When the GC decides that no thread has a reference to a particular object, directly or indirectly, it reclaims the memory occupied by that object.

Therefore:

```
 Person p = new Person("John"); // "John" won't be GCd because p refers to it
 p = new Person("Peter"); // Now nothing refers to "John" to the GC can clear it away
```

References also cease to exist when they go out of scope:

```
  Person someMethod() {
      Person p1 = new Person("John");
      Person p2 = new Person("Peter");
      return p2; // the caller will probably use the reference to p2,
                 // but after this method ends, p1 is definitely available
                 // for GC.
  }
```

All this means it's pretty difficult to write a Java program which leaks memory.

The Garbage Collector does periodic cleanups, and you can watch it at work with tools such as *VisualVM*. You get a "sawtooth" effect, with memory usage accumulating then dropping sharply each time the GC runs.

One way to leak memory in Java is to store references in some structure you don't really need, or don't maintain properly.

```
 Person p = new Person("John");
 irrelevantSet.add(p);
 p = new Person("Peter");
```

Here, the GC can't clear away "John" because `irrelevantSet` contains a reference to it. Usually you put an object in a structure such as a Set because you don't *want* it to be cleared away; but you can sometimes get into situations where you forget that objects you really don't need your program to have any more, are still held in a structure.

---

Your example:

```
 Person p1 = new Person("John");
 Person p2 = new Person("Peter");
 p1 = p2;  // p1 = p2 = "John". "Peter" will be GCd.
```

It's not unusual to see Java code with lines like this:

```
 Person p1 = new Person("John");
 doSomethingWith(p1);
 p1 = null; // let the GC take back the Person
```

However if you structure code properly -- use local variables and short methods -- this shouldn't be necessary, and I consider it bad style.

Answer (score 0):

No, There's no memory leak on your code.

You may analyze it yourself using [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Refer for more information: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072864/heap-dump-and-analysis-with-visualvm.html